# Where do I submit a bug report for video scope on ubuntu phone?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, scopes

I can't seem to find the right place to submit a bug report for the Video scope on the Ubuntu phone. Its not listed here https://launchpad.net/unity-scopes

Answer (score 2):

It's probably the Unity Media Scanner Scope ([unity-scope-mediascanner](https://launchpad.net/unity-scope-mediascanner)). At least the settings screen with "Display results from My Videos" is in there.

I just search the source code using Google like that:

```
"<some phrase from the UI>" site:https://launchpad.net
```